# VHDL Concurrent statement comparison

Tags: vhdl

I am learning VHDL and came across this example of 2 functionally equivalent ways of implementing the same thing. But I am having trouble understanding how they are functionally equivalent.

My confusion is in the 3 concurrent statement picture. Since they are all executed at the same time that means that F3 gets set to (A1 or A2). But since A1 and A2 are getting set at the same time that F3 is getting set, doesn't that mean A1 and A2 do not actually have values yet when F3 tries to get assigned to (A1 or A2)?

Thanks

[image: 1 concurrent statement]

[image: 3 concurrent statements]

Comment: This may help. [BASIC CONCEPTS SIMULATION MODEL DELTA TIME - CONCURRENCY](http://dea.unsj.edu.ar/sda/31_DeltaTime_Concept.pdf). The first point is telling - "VHDL was designed as a simulation language, so to understand the language we must examine the behavior of a VHDL simulator".

Comment: thank you @user8352 your answer lead me to figuring it out. I answered the question in a way that makes sense to me and posted it on this thread. I think me showing the screenshots how I did will make it clear for other beginners like me.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of technical details to simulation and instantiation. But I'd like to avoid the algebraic approaches and just focus on the visual aspects for a moment. It may help. (You've avoided variables, but I may decide to address them for a moment below.)

It's probably better if you think of a ***signal*** as the same thing as a named ***wire***. So when you write the following within a begin..end block:

```
A1 <= ((NOT L) AND (NOT M) AND N);
A2 <= L and M;
F3 <= A1 or A2;
```

All it is doing is the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4C3pG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the order of the statements don't matter. They could be arranged in any permutation you wanted. The same schematic results from those three statements, regardless of order.

Your signal names are just ***wires*** with names. That's all. The only difference between the above and what results from:

```
F3 <= ((NOT L) AND (NOT M) AND N) or (L and M);
```

is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdRgtN.png)</sup>

In other words, two named wires are no longer named. That's all that happens. Since naming is a matter of convenience for humans, not for circuits, it makes no difference in the combinatorial result.

Now, there is a difference with VHDL variables. If you are familiar with C, it's perhaps better to *see* a variable as if it were the equivalent of a C #define and not as a physical ***wire*** in a schematic.

For example, if **A1** and **A2** were variables instead of signals, then:

```
A1 := ((NOT L) AND (NOT M) AND N);
A2 := L and M;
F3 <= A1 or A2;
```

Would produce the same logic as in the second schematic above, except perhaps the following might be a better way of seeing it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8qqwH.png)</sup>

No wires are really named **A1** or **A2**. Instead, the expressions for **A1** and **A2** were, in effect, inserted into the wire-assignment for **F3**. (You could still label those wires, mentally. But it's better to imagine they aren't named at all, but instead just used to replace the symbols in the final line where the ***wire*** **F3** is assigned.)

There are some subtle and not-so-subtle results from this difference.

In VHDL gate-level logic, you can add an ***after*** clause to a signal assignment. But you cannot do that with a variable. That's because a variable isn't a wire representing the output of some logic. It really is more like the C language's #define.

So you can write:

```
A1 <= ((NOT L) AND (NOT M) AND N) after 3 ns;
A2 <= L and M after 1 ns;
F3 <= A1 or A2 after 2 ns;
```

And this will affect simulation (but not instantiation.)

But, if **A1** and **A2** were variables, you cannot write:

```
A1 := ((NOT L) AND (NOT M) AND N) after 3 ns;    -- error!
A2 := L and M after 1 ns;                        -- error!
F3 <= A1 or A2 after 2 ns;
```

Variables cannot have delays like that. The above would be an error. This is because the variables replace their mnemonics found in ***wire*** assignments (the **<=** lines.) Variables are not wires. (Besides, the very idea of subexpressions with ***after*** clauses together with a final ***after*** clause on that ***wire*** assignment line would be quite confusing!)

Where all this actually gets interesting is in sequential logic (RTL) where you are indicating sensitivity to a std_logic signal's clock edge. Then the differences in variables and signal wires becomes far more interesting.

Assuming **A1** and **A2** are variables:

```
if rising_edge(CLK) then
    A1 := ((NOT L) AND (NOT M) AND N);
    A2 := L and M;
    F3 <= A1 or A2;
end if;
```

You get this (where only **F3** depends on the rising edge of **CLK** (std_logic type), as **A1** and **A2** are more like "macros" representing some logic but not actual ***wires***):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftiiog.png)</sup>

A variable represents a block of logic and not a wire. It is meaningless to imagine that the block is sensitive to an edge of **CLK**. Only signal wires can be. When a wire is placed within an if..end that depends upon a rising or falling edge of some other std_logic wire, this infers an FF. As a variable isn't a wire, an FF cannot be inferred for a variable.

That is very much different from the following case where **A1** and **A2** are signals/wires (which do depend upon the rising edge of **CLK**):

```
if rising_edge(CLK) then
    A1 <= ((NOT L) AND (NOT M) AND N);
    A2 <= L and M;
    F3 <= A1 or A2;
end if;
```

When you instead get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHCiKK.png)</sup>

Hopefully, that helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

VHDL shouldn't be treated like a programming language. VHDL is a hardware description language. Whatever codes written in concurrent section have nothing to do with "time", and the order of codes doesn't matter. That means it's equivalent to a circuit operating at "all times", i.e. independent of time.

Comment: That all depends on your definition of programming language. You will find that in functional programming languages like Haskell, the statement order doesn't describe temporal sequence either; a  VHDL concurrent region behaves similar to that.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, but that's a tiny minority compared to the vast majority of software which is written in procedural programming languages. So there's no confusion caused by the term 'programming language'.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a sequential program, but a description of connections in a circuit, so `F3` is connected to the output of an *OR* gate that has its inputs connected to `A1` and `A2`.

The difference between the two approaches is whether you give names to intermediates. A similar thing can happen in sequential languages, for example in C the statements

```
int a = b + c * d;
```

and

```
int t = c * d;
int a = b + t;
```

are equivalent.

The book is a bit confusing here -- the equivalence is not a result of concurrency.

Due to the concurrency, you can also swap the VHDL statements and still get the same result, while that doesn't work in C.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time researching what @user8352 linked me to, delta cycles. I'm sure if you are experienced with VHDL then you can answer my question easily.

I took screenshots of how I was able to see everything step by step. The code, the simulation and a table explaining the current time, current signal values and time until the next event are shown in each screenshot.

I understand what they mean now, the result is the same, just the number of delta cycles are different. That is what I had imagined (some sort of timing difference) but could not explain why.

[image: Listing 4.7 Explained]
[image: Listing 4.8 Explained]